# IPhone as a gateway for iot device -- Azure IOT HUB

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-suite, azure-iot-central

Is there a way  in azure iot hub.. where we can have  ios device act as a gateway for leaf nodes like raspberry pi or other decive's to sends/receive data from azure iot hub.

Is there any iOS sdk available for the same

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has released a port of our Azure IoT Hub C SDK for iOS platform. You can use device and service SDK directly. The libraries are available on CocoaPod, a popular package manager for iOS, and the source code is available on GitHub. Please refer to this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-iot-sdk-ios-support/).

Learn more about how to turn your iOS device into an IoT device:

- [Send telemetry from a device to an IoT hub (Swift)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-ios)
- [Send cloud-to-device message from an application (Swift)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-ios-swift-c2d)
- [Samples in Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-ios)